# EF Insert a property with navigation properties, while ignoring the navigation properties recursively

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm using .Net6 core, with EF code first approach.

I've got classes like

```
class Foo {
   [Required]
   private Bar Bar {get; set;}; 
   ...
}

class Bar {
   [Required]
   private BarChild BarChild {get; set;}; 
   ...
}

class BarChild {
   ...
}
```

Now I want to insert an instance of `Foo` in the database like this:

```
Context.Comments.Add(foo); 
Context.SaveChanges();
```

Now this gives me the error 'unique constraint failed ...' because `Foo` has a navigation property to `Bar` but `Bar` already exists in the database.

I Found a solution to this:

```
Context.Entry(foo.Bar).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
Context.Entry(foo.Bar.BarChild).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
```

Note that I have to set the state of `BarChild` to unchanged as well even though I already did so for `Bar`.

The thing is some classes have quite a bit of navigation properties, which in their turn have navigation properties as well, and thus my question, is there a better way to 'ignore' these navigation properties?

I can't just set them to `null` since in the database there is a foreign key referencing those navigation properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For other options that don't involve tricking the change tracker into thinking it has already seen what is actually a new Bar, if you have an ID property for Bar in Foo you can set that instead and EF will write a Foo that relates to an existing Bar without trying to write a Bar too

```
class Foo {
   int BarId {get; set;}
   Bar Bar {get; set;}; 
   ...
}
```

If you know the DB contains Bar 3 and you want your new Foo's Bar to be that Bar you can:

```
db.Foos.Add(new Foo { BarId = 3, ... });
db.Save...
```

---

You can also download the existing Bar:

```
var f = new Foo { Bar = db.Bars.Find(3) };
db.Foos.Add(f);
db.Save...
```

..that's maybe less popular because it's a bit of a waste of resources, unless you need to retrieve the Bar to do other things to it too